# Create a new angularjs route (IStateProvider) without using parent index

Tags: angularjs, routes, parent

Currently there is an existing website already that uses the main index as the parent index. All the other view and controller uses the parent's side navigation and header. Basically it uses the ui-view main for each of these controllers to display their content.

However, I now need to create a new page within the same project that needs to not use the parent's header and side navigation. Rewriting the whole children will take too much time because there are literally hundreds of views.

Any recommendation for the new route to break out of the iframe or parent?

EDIT: Or perhaps is it possible to hide the parent data while in my new page?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this in my project :

```
 $stateProvider.state('landing', {
        url: "/landing",
        templateUrl: "/appViews/landing.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('landingCtrl'),
        title: 'Landing'

        //************ Set up b2b states*****************************************************************
    }).state('b2b', {
        url: "/b2b",
        template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>',
        abstract: true
    }).state('b2b.login', {
        url: '/login',
        template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>',
        abstract: true
    });
```

as you see landing and b2b use completely two different templates here.